# Get Drop Target During jQuery Draggable Drag Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm learning to use the [jQuery UI Draggable Widget](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/). I need to do some special handling in response to the [Drag event](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag).

From my Drag event handler, is there a way to get the current drop target--that is, the element that the mouse is currently hovering over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In drag event there is no way to get current hovering element, however you can get this from "Droppable" drop event. Check this [JQFAQ.com](http://jqfaq.com/how-to-know-on-which-element-an-item-is-currently-being-dragged-on/) topic, which will explain how to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Would be nice to do from Draggable but perhaps I can make it work from Droppable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **hoverClass** attribute in the droppable target and check which drop zone has the hoverClass in the drag event.

It's a little bit hacky but it would work.